# Run bash script from another script and exit first script while second is running

Tags: linux, bash

First bash script is:

```
./second #takes too long
```

I want kill first bash script while second bash script is still running.

Can I do that?

**UPDATE**

First script run by cronjob!

Comment: Provide your scripts, not just a meaningless script name.  Is the first script the parent process of the second?

Comment: Are you asking how to run the second script in the background so the first script can continue? `./second &`

Comment: @tristan yes first script run second script

Comment: Then terminating the parent process will terminate the child.  You can halt execution of whatever logic/actions in the first script, but it's process must live for the child to not be terminated.

Comment: Any other way with `tmux` or something else?

Comment: Not always, you can `disown` a process, making it run independently of its parent. "that other guy" already gave you an answer, just add a `&` to the end of the process call. Read more about disowning processes [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-disown-command-examples-usage-syntax/) (found from a quick google search).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the last thing that the first script does is to call the second script, then do this:

```
exec ./second
```

which *replaces* the first script's process with the second.

otherwise

```
nohup ./second &
disown
```

Answer (score 1):

For Linux you would use the "kill" command after obtaining the PID of the program you wish to exit-

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_kill.htm

I don't know how you would get the PID automatically via a script however.

It appears you can also use "pkill" to terminate processes by name-

Ex-

```
pkill -9 ping
```

Or killall-

```
killall firefox
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ps-kill-and-nice-to-manage-processes-in-linux

**The answer below applies to BATCH files, not bash. I read the question wrong.**

You can close an instance by getting the PID. You can also use this bit of code-

```
taskkill /f /im "x"
```

Where "x" is the name of the program you wish to close, as it would appear in the Task Manager.

Explanation of the parameters I gave-

/im   ImageName   : Specifies the image name of the process to be terminated. Use the wildcard (*) to specify all image names.

/f   : Specifies that process(es) be forcefully terminated. This parameter is ignored for remote processes; all remote processes are forcefully terminated.

More info-
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

Comment: Argh. Sorry, I read "bash" as "batch". This is not a correct answer to this question.

Comment: Added some additional information that is hopefully relevant to this question.

Comment: Killing the parent PID will stop the child process.  This is a question of job control, not finding the correct command for killing processes.